# The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available. - Embedded Compact 7 - Device CP6606-0001-0020

Tags: embedded, windows-ce

I have followed the steps available at

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6012.how-to-use-the-remote-tools-framework-

I have a Beckhoff CP6606 Panel PC with Windows Embedded Compact 7. It has a ARM Cortex A8 processor. I have configured IP address of Panel PC(192.168.xxx.101) and Development computer(192.168.xxx.102) on same subnet. However, I had the error, Device Connect Failed.

After some web research, I realized I had to install Windows Embedded Compact 7 on the development PC, which I have done only for ARM v7 architecture, which i had rechecked from wiki about ARM A8 processor. Now, I get a failure message as

"Failed to Connect - The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available". I tried calling Microsoft support but had no luck. My Configuration is;

Target Device -

Beckhoff CP6606-0001-0020 (http://download.beckhoff.com/download/document/IndustPC/CP6606-0001-0020de.pdf)
Development PC -

Windows 7 32 Bit Professional
VS2008 with SP1(Inkl. Update for Embedded 7)
Embedded Compact 7 - University Edition
Remote Tools v1.10
Communication -

Ethernet(RJ-45)
- Any more information required will be furnished

- Any advice/tips/suggestions would be considered until I have resolved this issue . Thank you.

EDIT: USB-A to USB-A connection failed

Comment: Try turning off UAC and rebooting. If that doesn't help, try [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see what happens leading up to the error.

Comment: Thanks for the Input Paul. Will see how it goes further.

Comment: Hi Paul. Disabled the UAC . The ProcMon show's no anomalies. All that I see on the Process "devenv.exe" is SUCCESS. Does the Image version of OEM-WinCE Panel make any difference to the steps I followed.

Comment: Hi Paul, Had a conversation finally with Beckhoff. Seems it is a new one for them as I am still waiting for a solution from them.

Comment: devenv.exe isn't the only process to look at. There is probably an activesync process in there too. devenv.exe may spawn child processes during the connection as well.

Comment: When you connect by USB, does Device Manager show the correct USB driver loaded?

Comment: I have finally got a response from Beckhoff. I was not able to get the USB driver over the Beckhoff Website and they have confirmed that the USB is only for peripherals(Maus & Keyboard).

Answer (score -3):

I finally have the solution. Will be available at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2262esYv4gGMFBOWEZIelA3RFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How about publishing it here and not hiding it behind a google service that needs login?

Comment: Hey phlik, I could have done that if I had known how to add pdf to SO. Working to make the doc public without login requirement.

Comment: @phlik - Its open to access. Let me know if you still cannot read it. Thanks mate.

Comment: Downvote for putting the solution somewhere the link is no longer available